# Assets Images not being found

Tags: assets, image, import

When importing local user assets to a development server with sftp (including a database import), some of the assets are missing (it gives the impression to be random). Even after updated the indexes.

[image]

When I try to access them directly in the browser, I get a Page not Found, but they are well present on the server, within the same folder/name.

How It is possible ?

Comment: Maybe you were on a case insensitive file system and you imported to a case sensitive file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that, somehow, the files and the foldernames containing special characters where not well handled (In my case, a lot of é and è).

Removing the special characters, and adding `'convertFilenamesToAscii' => true` to the general.php config file for future edition / creation / upload resolved this issue for me.